# Antonym of “overlook”!

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is an appropriate antonym for *overlooks* in following context:

> This formula, in some cases, overlooks some significant factors and, in some other cases, ____ some other insignificant factors.

I’m looking for something in the sense of *taking into account unnecessarily much.*
Maybe *scrutinizes?*

Comment: Surely 'takes into account'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. 

Not really. Here, "overlook" has a subtle meaning of "not taking into account enough". I'm looking for something like "taking into account unnecessarily too much". Does that make sense at all?

Comment: The definition that you would like 'overlook' to have does not appear in any of the six dictionaries I've just looked in. Close-voting on 'lack of clarity' grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is not clear then? I tried to use the simplest structure and vocabs to convey my intent.

Comment: You mean 'does not pay sufficient attention to'; 'overlooks' is absolute. The opposite of 'does not pay sufficient attention to' is perhaps best phrased as 'takes fully into account'.

Comment: In that context, "over-emphasizes".  But it's highly context-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

> Overlook means to fail to notice something or to not pay attention to something.

So possible words which could mean the opposite are

> [**Observe**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observe): notice or perceive (something) and register it as being significant.
>
> [**Notice**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notice): become aware of; the fact of observing or paying attention to something.
>
> [**Consider**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consider): to look attentively, or to take into account.

You can frame this sentence as:

> The formula couldn’t really be relied upon as it considered many insignificant aspects/factors while overlooking the important ones.

Comment: Haha, yeah you cannot upvote the answers yet, but I guess you should be able to mark this response as the correct answer. And happy to help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

> This formula, in some cases, overlooks some significant factors and
>   in some other cases ***seems obsessed with*** insignificant factors.

**obsess**, from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obsess):

> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to dominate or preoccupy the thoughts, feelings, or desires of (a  person); beset, trouble, or haunt persistently or abnormally:
>      Suspicion obsessed him.    verb (used without object)
> 2. to think about something unceasingly or persistently; dwell  obsessively upon something

And then the same reference gives a perfect example for the OP:

> The professor known as Wittgenstein (and Iyer) obsess about the notion
>   of thought itself on almost every page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider ***overemphasize***, consisting of:

- > **[over-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over-#Prefix)**
  >   […]
  >   excessively
- > **[emphasize](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emphasize#English)** […]
  >   *(transitive)* To stress, give emphasis or extra weight to (something).

So, you could say:

> This formula, overlooks some significant factors while overemphasizing insignificant factors, depending on the case.